# Get current view on the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, spfx

Im trying to get current view on SPFX extension but i dont know the code..

I know we can get the current list by

```
this.context.pageContext.list.title
```

Is ther somethig like this for view??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(this.context.listView)
```

[image]

Comment: That didnt work.. i solved it by getting the url, and the view id in the url